# What will happen if queryset only return some values of model in django generic view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Assume:

I have a model:

```
class ModelA(model):
    field a = intfield
    field b = intfiedl
```

I create a view and refine queryset:

```
class TestView(DetailView):
     queryset = ModelA.objects.values("a")
```

what will happen if I use this view. Will the b field of 'object' be empty or raise an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `values` call, you don't get a normal queryset consisting of model instances, you get a ValuesQuerySet consisting of dictionaries. The only values in those dictionaries are those you specify in the call to values. So, there will not even be a key in the dict for `b`.

Don't do this unless you have a very good reason.